# Remove a row from all dataframes in a list if NA value in one of the rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nan

I have a list of `data.frames` of equal size. There exist missing data in different rows and columns of each `data.frame`. I would like to remove the row of each data frame for which one of `data.frames` have a row that contains a `NaN`. The current `lapply` and `na.omit` code I have removes each row corresponding to the specific `data.frame` which makes sense as it goes through each `data.frame` in the list before moving on to the next one. However, I would like to make it so that if an `NaN` exists in one row of a `data.frame` that row gets removed from all other data.frames

Some example code:

```
#Make list
ls <- list(x1=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(2,3,4,5),c=c(3,4,NaN,6)),
           x2=data.frame(a=c(1,NaN,3,4),b=c(2,3,4,5),c=c(3,4,5,6)))
#Desired output
lscalc <- list(x1=data.frame(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,5),c=c(3,6)),
               x2=data.frame(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,5),c=c(3,6)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the datasets have the same number of rows, get the `row` index from all the datasets first and then loop over the `list` and remove those rows

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(lapply(ls, function(x) which(is.na(x), arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])))
lapply(ls, function(x) x[!seq_len(nrow(x)) %in% un1, ])
$x1
  a b c
1 1 2 3
4 4 5 6

$x2
  a b c
1 1 2 3
4 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using `complete.cases()`, though otherwise along the same lines as @akrun's.

```r
#Make list
l <- list(x1=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(2,3,4,5),c=c(3,4,NaN,6)),
           x2=data.frame(a=c(1,NaN,3,4),b=c(2,3,4,5),c=c(3,4,5,6)))
#Desired output
lcalc <- list(x1=data.frame(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,5),c=c(3,6)),
               x2=data.frame(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,5),c=c(3,6)))

inds <- lapply(l, \(x)which(!complete.cases(x)))
inds <- unique(do.call(c, inds))
lcalc2 <- lapply(l, \(x)x[-inds, ])
lcalc2
#> $x1
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 4 4 5 6
#> 
#> $x2
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 4 4 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>